# Java 2d space gravity not working

Tags: java

I am trying to make a 2d game in java with realistic physics. The game is supposed to be set in space from a top down view. The best way I can explain the view is to use this link: [3d graph found one gooogle images with search "3d graph xyz"](http://3drockstar.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/3d-coordinates-300x261.gif). The view is supposed to be set so that you are looking from the top of the +y towards the -y.

In the game I currently only have it showing one sun and one planet to test the gravity. However, when I run the game the planet only moves away from the sun in a towards the bottom right. I believe this to be due to me misusing the equation when moving it to java. For reference the equations I used were Newton's Law of Universal Gravitation (F=(G*M1*M2)/D^2) and Newton's Second Law of Motion (F=MA, but used as A=F/M).

In short, My question is what did I do wrong with my equations? I will post all my code below, but fair warning it is designed to be expanded upon so there is a lot of excess currently.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Core class:

```
package src.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import src.main.input.Input;
import src.main.input.InputHandler;
import src.main.map.Map;

public class Core extends JPanel
{

private static InputHandler iHandler = new InputHandler();
private static Input input = new Input(iHandler);
private long ticks;
private Map map;
public static Dimension SIZE;

public static Random rand = new Random();

public Core(Dimension d)
{
    setPreferredSize(d);

    SIZE = d;
    ticks = 0;
    map = new Map(SIZE.width, SIZE.height);

    start();
}

public synchronized void update()
{
    ticks++;
    iHandler.update(ticks);
    /*if (iHandler.getWheelRotation() != 0)
    {
        int i = iHandler.getWheelRotation();
        map.changeMagnification(i > 0);
        if (i > 0)
            i--;
        else
            i++;
        iHandler.setWheelRotation(i);
        if (i < 0 && map.getMagnification() == 0)
            iHandler.setWheelRotation(0);
        if (i > 0 && map.getMagnification() == Map.MAX_MAGNIFY)
            iHandler.setWheelRotation(0);
    }*/

    map.update(ticks);
}

public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g2)
{
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) g2;
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, SIZE.width, SIZE.height);

    map.draw(g);
}

public void start()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

                update();
                repaint();

                time = (1000 / 128) - (System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

                if (time > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(time);
                    } catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        Rectangle r = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();

        public void run()
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setContentPane(new Core(new Dimension(r.width, r.height)));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            frame.addKeyListener(input);
            frame.addMouseListener(input);
            frame.addMouseMotionListener(input);
            frame.addMouseWheelListener(input);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Map Class:

```
package src.main.map;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import src.main.Core;
import src.main.celestials.SolarSystem;

public class Map
{

private int magnification;
public static final int MAX_MAGNIFY = 15;
private ArrayList<SolarSystem> systems = new ArrayList<SolarSystem>();

public Map(int x, int y)
{
    SolarSystem s=new SolarSystem(new Point(500,500), "sun", (int) (1.9891 * Math.pow(10, 30)));
    s.addPlanet(new Point(550, 550), "planet");
    systems.add(s);


}

public void update(long ticks)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < systems.size(); i++)
        systems.get(i).update(ticks);
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);



    magnification= 1;


    for(int i=0; i<systems.size(); i++)
    {
        systems.get(i).draw(g, magnification);
    }


}



public int getMagnification()
{
    return magnification;
}

public void changeMagnification(boolean bigger)
{
    if (bigger)
        magnification++;
    else
        magnification--;

    if (magnification > MAX_MAGNIFY)
        magnification = MAX_MAGNIFY;
    if (magnification < 1)
        magnification = 1;
}
}
```

Body Class:

```
package src.main.celestials;

import java.awt.Point;

import src.main.Core;
import src.main.map.Map;

public abstract class Body
{
protected String name;
protected double x, y, mass;

public Body(Point t, String s, int m)
{
    x = t.x;
    y = t.y;
    name = s;
    mass = m;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public double getMass() {
    return mass;
}

public void setMass(double mass) {
    this.mass = mass;
}

public abstract void update(long ticks);
}
```

SolarSystem Class:

```
package src.main.celestials;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import src.main.celestials.Planet;

public class SolarSystem extends Body {

private ArrayList<Planet> planets = new ArrayList<Planet>();
private BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[7];
private BufferedImage sun;

public SolarSystem(Point t, String s, int m) {
    super(t, s, m);

    try
    {
        String loc = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\Proof of Concept Game\\Proof of Concept Game\\Gravity Test\\Suns\\";
        images[0] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_Blue.png"));
        images[1] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_BlueWhite.png"));
        images[2] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_Orange.png"));
        images[3] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_Red.png"));
        images[4] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_White.png"));
        images[5] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_Yellow.png"));
        images[6] = ImageIO.read(new File(loc + "Sun_YellowWhite.png"));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sun = images[(int) (Math.random() * images.length)];
}
//earth mass:5.97219 × 10^24KG
    //sun mass: 1.9891 × 10^30KG
    //sun/earth ratio: 333060.4016
@Override
public void update(long ticks) {
    // run interactions between planets and solar systems
    for(int i=0; i<planets.size(); i++)
    {
        planets.get(i).setxAccel(genAccelX(i));
        planets.get(i).setyAccel(genAccelY(i));
    }

    // update using acceleration and velocity
    for(int i=0; i<planets.size(); i++)
    {
        planets.get(i).update(ticks);
    }

}
public void addPlanet(Point point, String name)
{
    planets.add(new Planet(point, name, (int) (5.97219*Math.pow(10, 24))));
}
/*public double genAccel(int i)
{
    double G=6.67*Math.pow(10, -11);
    double Dx=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getX()-getX(), 2);
    double Dy=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getY()-getY(), 2);
    double D=Math.sqrt(Dx+Dy);
    return G*planets.get(i).getMass()/Math.pow(D, 2);

}
public double genAccelX(int i)
{
    double Dx=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getX()-getX(), 2);
    double Dy=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getY()-getY(), 2);
    double D=Math.sqrt(Dx+Dy);
    double A=genAccel(i);
    return Dx*A/D;
}
public double genAccelY(int i)
{
    double Dx=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getX()-getX(), 2);
    double Dy=Math.pow(planets.get(i).getY()-getY(), 2);
    double D=Math.sqrt(Dx+Dy);
    double A=genAccel(i);
    return Dy*A/D;
}*/

public double genAccelX(int i)
{
    double x1=0;
    double x2=0;
    /*if(getX()>planets.get(i).getX())
    {*/
        x1=getX();
        x2=planets.get(i).getX();
    /*}
    else
    {
        x1=planets.get(i).getX();
        x2=getX();
    }*/
    double G=6.67e-11;
    double d=x1-x2;
    d*=d;
    planets.get(i).setxForce((G*getMass()*planets.get(i).getMass())/d);
    return planets.get(i).getxForce()/planets.get(i).getMass();
}
public double genAccelY(int i)
{
    double y1=0;
    double y2=0;
    /*if(getY()<planets.get(i).getY())
    {*/
        y1=getY();
        y2=planets.get(i).getY();
    /*}
    else
    {
        y1=planets.get(i).getY();
        y2=getY();
    }*/
    double G=6.67e-11;
    double d=y1-y2;
    d*=d;
    planets.get(i).setyForce((G*getMass()*planets.get(i).getMass())/d);
    return planets.get(i).getyForce()/planets.get(i).getMass();
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g, int magnification) {
    g.drawImage(sun, (int)(x) * magnification + 2, (int)(y) * magnification + 2, 50, 50, null);
    for(int i=0; i<planets.size(); i++)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.PINK);
        g.fillOval((int)planets.get(i).getX(), (int)planets.get(i).getY(), 20, 20);
    }
}
}
```

Planet Class:

```
package src.main.celestials;

import java.awt.Point;

public class Planet extends Body {

double xForce, yForce, xAccel, yAccel, xVel, yVel;


public Planet(Point t, String s, int m) {
    super(t, s, m);

}

public double getxForce() {
    return xForce;
}

public void setxForce(double xForce) {
    this.xForce = xForce;
}

public double getyForce() {
    return yForce;
}

public void setyForce(double yForce) {
    this.yForce = yForce;
}

public double getxAccel() {
    return xAccel;
}

public void setxAccel(double xAccel) {
    this.xAccel = xAccel;
}

public double getyAccel() {
    return yAccel;
}

public void setyAccel(double yAccel) {
    this.yAccel = yAccel;
}

public double getxVel() {
    return xVel;
}

public void setxVel(double xVel) {
    this.xVel = xVel;
}

public double getyVel() {
    return yVel;
}

public void setyVel(double yVel) {
    this.yVel = yVel;
}

@Override
public void update(long ticks) {
    xVel+=xAccel;
    yVel+=yAccel;
    x+=xVel;
    y+=yVel;
    System.out.println("X: "+(int)x+"\t\t"+"Y: "+(int)y);
    System.out.println("XVel: "+xVel+"\t\t"+"YVel: "+yVel);
    System.out.println("XAccel: "+xAccel+"\t"+"YAccel: "+yAccel);

}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking us to check your math?

Comment: In a very long way I guess

Comment: Then you're in the wrong forum.

Comment: This is my first post, sorry. could you link me to the correct forum?

Comment: It's difficult to say. There are math and physics StackExchange sites but I doubt they will deal with your Java code.

Comment: So where should I post this? I thought I was in the java forum?

Comment: I think you should debug your own code and check if the variables have the expected values and the result of your math is the correct one. Even if you don't find the error right away, you would probably get a better idea where the issue is and be able to make a more concise post about that particular problem.

Comment: I did that already and can't figure out where the error is, that is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, concerning your comment

> *I thought I was in the java forum?*

(also @PM77-1 :) StackOverflow is **not** a forum at all! Also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92110 . It is a "Question And Answer" site, and this imposes some constraints on *how* you should ask, and what to expect as a response. (Actually, the fact that I'm writing this here is already a "violation" of these rules, and I'm risking downvotes for that). The question in its current form is hardly suitable for *any* site of the StackExchange network. If you write a question here, then you should ...

- Include a *clear* and *focussed* question (namely, one that goes beyond "What is wrong with my code?")
- Provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (preferably, if possible and appropriate, as a single code block, with no dependencies to other, unrelated classes, and no dependencies to external resources etc.)

---

That said, regarding your actual "question": The formula that you are using is correct. But it is not properly implemented. The formula is

[image: Law]

(according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation))

The "r" refers to the *distance* between the centers of mass of the objects.

In your code, you tried to implement this in the `SolarSystem#genAccelX` and `SolarSystem#genAccelY` methods:

```
...
double x1=0;
double x2=0;
x1=getX();
x2=planets.get(i).getX();
double G=6.67e-11;
double d=x1-x2;
d*=d;
planets.get(i).setxForce((G*getMass()*planets.get(i).getMass())/d);
return planets.get(i).getxForce()/planets.get(i).getMass();
```

But the problem is that you are computing this *separately* for x and for y. Thus, the resulting force is losing its actual direction (and is "wrong" anyhow).

To put it simply: The `d` that you are computing there is *negative*, because the planet should move to the *left*. But by taking `d*=d`, it becomes *positive* (and this, the planet is moving to the *right*)

---

The solution:

You should describe all positions, velocities and forces as *vectors* instead of computing everything separately for x and y. Basically, it will boil down to a class like

```
class Vector {
    private double x, y;

    // Setters, getters...
    ....

    double distanceSquared(Vector other) {
        double dx = x - other.x;
        double dy = y - other.y;
        return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    }
    double distance(Vector other) {
        return Math.sqrt(distanceSquared(other));
    }

    // Some other useful methods:
    double length() { ... }
    void normalize(double factor) { ... }
    void scale(double factor) { ... }
    void add(Vector other) { ... }
    void addScaled(double factor, Vector other) { ... }
    void sub(Vector other) { ... }
    Vector difference(Vector other) { ... }
}
```

Given such a class, the method for computing the force and acceleration could *roughly* look like this:

```
// The bodies here may be the sun and a planet:
public double computeForceStrength(Body body0, Body body1)
{
    double G=6.67e-11;
    Vector position0 = body0.getPosition();
    Vector position1 = body1.getPosition();
    double distanceSquared = position0.distanceSquared(position1);

    // The formula from wikipedia:
    double f = G * body0.getMass() * body1.getMass() / distanceSquared;
    return f;
}

void performSomeTimeStep(Body body0, Body body1)
{
    Vector direction = position1.difference(position0);
    direction.normalize();

    double f = computeForceStrength(body0, body1);
    body0.getVelocity().addScaled(direction,  f / body0.getMass());
    body1.getVelocity().addScaled(direction, -f / body1.getMass());
}
```

(just to show the basic idea - again: There are *many* degrees of freedom)

---

There are several other (stylistic) issues with the code, but ... when it is working, you may want to submit it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ....

Comment: I apologize for the poor formatting of this post and I will do better for my next question. This is a huge help and I would vote up if my reputation was high enough. There are a few things I don't understand what you mean and if you could answer a few questions about those I would appreciate it immensely. The first few parts I don't understand are in the "some other useful methods" part of your Vector class, such as what normalize, scale, sub, and difference intend. I also didn't understand what the last two lines of code in your performSomeTimeStep method intend. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Strauscon Normalize: Scale the vector to have a length of 1. Scale: Multiply x and y with a factor. Sub: Subtract another vector. Difference: Compute the difference between the vector and another vector. (This was only a sketch. *Think* about the appropriate methods on your own!). The last two lines in the code change the velocity of the bodies, by adding the acceleration (f/m), in the appropriate direction.

Comment: Thanks. I just had no idea what you intended. I probably won't need some of those methods and will need some others that are not listed. Again thanks for the help.